# I am using a REST API which produces xml results. Thre is a node called zone. How can I change the value of the node using php?

Tags: php, xml, rest, xml-parsing

I am using an API that produces an xml results file. Here is the URI example

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('https://api.url.com/v2/result?key=mykey&zone=all&q='.$first_name.'%20'.$last_name));
```

In the URI &zone=all produces all of the results from all of the zones. I can change this to &zone=person but I need all results. In the next line I need a way to be able to change "zone" so that its value can be set according to the zone results that I want. You can see that I have tried to change it to book in the example below. It didnt work, I got an undefined constant error. I would really apprecite it if someone could tell me how to go about this please. I have not done a lot of work with XML lately.Thanks.

```
$title = $xml->zone->records->work->zone=book;

foreach ($title as $work) {
    foreach ($work->title as $titles) {
        echo "ID: ".$id."<br> <b>Title: </b>".$titles."<br>";
    }
}
```

Here is a copy of the returned xml file minus the keys.

```
<response>
<query>hello</query>
<zone name="url">
    <records s="*" n="0" total="0"/>
</zone>
<zone name="people">
    <records s="*" n="20" total="58" next="/result?q=hello&zone=people&s=AoIIRib9grewqTU2MGRkMS02YzgzLTQxYQ%3D" nextStart="AoIIRib9GD8NaWRlbnRpddfsdfk0OWQ=">
        <people id="1140172" url="/people/1140172">
        </people>
        <people id="1482231" url="/people/1482231">
        </people>
        <people id="832153" url="/people/832153">
        </people>
    </records>
</zone>
<zone name="collection">
    <records s="*" n="20" total="496" next="/result?q=hello&zone=collection&s=AoIIQsdfszdTIyNzc3MDUzNg%3D%3D" nextStart="AoIIQ3sHAysdfdszc3MDUzNg==">
        <work id="208227193" url="/work/208227193">
        </work>
        <work id="225096966" url="/work/225096966">
        </work>
        <work id="225096968" url="/work/225096968">
        </work>
    </records>
</zone>
<zone name="gazette">
    <records s="*" n="20" total="91239" next="/result?q=hello&zone=gazette&s=AoIIRdAyNjk3NzQ%3D" nextStart="AoIIgdfgek3NzQ=">
        <article id="249121748" url="/newspaper/249121748">
        </article>
        <article id="225072553" url="/newspaper/225072553">
        </article>
        <article id="249121741" url="/newspaper/249121741">
        </article>
    </records>
</zone>
<zone name="book">
    <records s="*" n="20" total="9245" next="/result?q=hello&zone=book&s=AogxMjk1Mg%3D%3D" nextStart="AoIIQ6HewytzdTIjk1Mg==">
        <work id="19554432" url="/work/19554432">
        </work>
        <work id="31597077" url="/work/31597077">
        </work>
        <work id="11135964" url="/work/11135964">
        </work>
    </records>
  </zone>
</response>
```

I really just want to be able to access the information from each zone. In the returned xml example I have reduced the result but inside of each zone there is more information. The results are too large to post into here.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your precise problem. What line of code is producing what error exactly?

Comment: Hi @ArSeN  I have provided an MCVE and hope that it all makes sense now. Thank you for the tip. I The line producing the error is the variable declaration. I need to  re-use the same line a several times changing only the value of the zone node.

Comment: What does `$xml` look like? A minimal structure example would be great! I can not imagine there is a node called `zone=book` since `=` should be a reserved character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML elements are treated like arrays so my solution was simple. To use access each zone I just needed to work out what position is was in the array and then use that in front of zone, see example below.

```
$title = $xml->zone[5]->records->work;
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php